How to get min and max date in SQL since branch the branch code changed
I have table as below. I'm using plsql



ID
BranchCode
StartDate
FinishDate




1111
89
07.06.2012
12.08.2013


1111
89
13.08.2013
09.03.2015


1111
1167
10.03.2015
30.09.2015


1111
548
01.10.2015
08.10.2015


1111
548
09.12.2015
31.07.2016


1111
548
01.08.2016
24.08.2017


1111
89
25.08.2017
19.03.2018


1111
89
20.03.2018
30.06.2019


1111
89
01.07.2019
today



And I want to find min and max dates each branch changes. I partioned based on branch_code and emp_ID but I couldn't what I want.
And this is what I want;



ID
BranchCode
MinStartDate
MaxFinishDate




1111
89
07.06.2012
09.03.2015


1111
1167
10.03.2015
30.09.2015


1111
548
01.10.2015
24.08.2017


1111
89
25.08.2015
today



I want to find min and max date when branch changed. And also calculate time between min and max date.

This is a gaps and islands problem, and we can use the difference in row numbers method here.
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID
                                   ORDER BY StartDate) rn1,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, BranchCode
                                   ORDER BY StartDate) rn2
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT
    ID,
    BranchCode,
    MIN(StartDate) AS MinStartDate,
    MAX(FinishDate) AS MaxFinishDate
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    ID,
    BranchCode,
    rn1 - rn2
ORDER BY
    ID,
    MIN(StartDate);

The basic idea here is to form a pseudo group column defined by the ID, BranchCode, and a difference in row numbers sequence.  Then, all we need to is aggregate and take the appropriate min/max.
